# <iframe> within google fusion table map tooltip

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I am using Fusion Tables to make a electoral map.
I'm an online journo with good html but very limited javascript skills.

I wanted to know, without using the Google API, was there a way to embed an iframe in a google fusion tables map tooltip?
WHen people click on the kml shape, I want them to see an interactive graph within the tooltip.

Here is the map with no tooltip, imagine there was an 
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col11+from+17wbN0-rd3mbdVNnPM6lGWufmIJXMfYLbeIG5zFo&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=-41.20861082449343&lng=147.35905204687504&t=1&z=7&l=col11&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=KML

The maps are created by combining kml with regular excell files.
I have the interactive graphs on a separate server and have the  handy.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is customize the info window inside Fusion Tables,  you can read all about it here:

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171216?hl=en

This will allow you to embed html into your infowindow,  instead of just being stuck with key/value pairs. You can also embed table values in the markup by enclosing the column name in braces.